# Use CSS for class and media query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, dry, dynamic-css

I have a menu bar that slides opened and closed. Its closed state is also what it looks like when the screen is sufficiently small. So, I basically have the same styles twice: once as a class and once as a media query.

Is there any way to avoid this?

**Edit ¹:**

I want to avoid having a media query style AND a class. It would be nice if there was some clever way of applying the same style via both a class and media query.

**Edit ²:**

Code example (for illustrative purposes):

```
menu {
    width: 100px;
}

menu.closed { /*triggered via class addition in javascript */
    width:10px;
}

@media (max-width:1000px) {
    menu { /*notice how this is the same as the closed class*/
        width:10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: fiddle? Your code? What have you tried yet?

Comment: I think you are stuck with this solution. There is really no "or" statement in CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have achieved the most compact code using *pure CSS*.

To achieve an even more [dry](/questions/tagged/dry) CSS code, you can use a *CSS preprocessor*.

They are tagged as [dynamic-css](/questions/tagged/dynamic-css). Some of them are [less](/questions/tagged/less), and [sass](/questions/tagged/sass).

---

**[Less example](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-variables)**:

```
@small-menu: 10px;

menu {
    width: 100px;
}

menu.closed {
    width: @small-menu;
}

@media (max-width:1000px) {
    menu {
        width: @small-menu;
    }
}
```

---

**[Sass example](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variables_)**:

```
$small-menu: 10px;

menu {
    width: 100px;
}

menu.closed {
    width: $small-menu;
}

@media (max-width:1000px) {
    menu {
        width: $small-menu;
    }
}
```